# There is another SharePoint MasterPage parameter different of Site and System

Tags: master-pages, sharepoint-branding

After the branding of a SharePoint site is done, I mean Site and System masterpages, there are still a few pages that uses the default style. My question is if we can change the master page for that pages too.

Example: http:///_layouts/settings.aspx
always looks like a fresh SharePoint

Answer (score 1):

The master page connected to Settings.aspx is /_layouts/Application.master. Many system pages use this master page but none of them use the custom or default master of the site.

Do know that modifying the file isn't supported by MS :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can refer your customized master page for those pages.